# Python requests module trying to find nonexistent cacert.pem when running in python-daemon environment built through pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-requests, pyinstaller, python-daemon

TL;DR: I use the python requests module in an application. I wish to compile this application into a distributable binary using pyinstaller, and also to make the process run in a daemon using python-daemon. Either using pyinstaller or python-daemon on their own has no issues, however, trying to both use pyinstaller AND python-daemon, the requests module suddenly decides that its cacert.pem is in `/tmp/[bunch of letters and numbers]/certifi/cacert.pem` and not anywhere else. Trying to bundle or load a copy of any cacert.pem results in another error, where requests is unable to verify the local issuer.

## Experiments

Given a simple python requests script (taken from w3 schools):

```
import requests
x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm')
print(x.text)
```

It outputs exactly as expected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>This is a Test Page</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

I then try compiling using pyinstaller (to a linux executable) using the following .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['/workspaces/tra-data-analysis/src'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[
                 "dnspython",
                 "requests",
             ],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [('W ignore', None, 'OPTION')],
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

And the compiled binary still behaves as expected.

Wrapping the request snippet as a daemon process using python-daemon:

```
import requests
import daemon
from daemon import pidfile
import os

e = open("errorlog", "w")
with daemon.DaemonContext(
        working_directory = os.getcwd(),
        pidfile = pidfile.TimeoutPIDLockFile("pidfile"),
        stderr=e
    ):

    x = requests.get('https://w3schools.com/python/demopage.htm')
    f = open("output", "w")
    f.write(x.text)
    f.close()
```

Still behaves as expected.

However, applying both the daemonization and the pyinstaller compilation, yields the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "requests/api.py", line 75, in get
  File "requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 417, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 228, in cert_verify
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /tmp/_MEIKPqY64/certifi/cacert.pem
[23066] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

Neither the compilation nor the daemonization by themselves cause this issue, yet when both are used together, they cause some conflict where the requests looks for cacert.pem in a temporary location that does not exist.

## Solutions already attempted

1. making a copy of certifi module's cacert.pem in the local directory, then using the parameter `verify="."`., Doing this yields the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
  File "urllib3/connection.py", line 416, in connect
  File "urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
  File "urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
  File "ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
  File "ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
  File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
  File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='w3schools.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /python/demopage.htm (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
  File "requests/api.py", line 75, in get
  File "requests/api.py", line 61, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
  File "requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
  File "requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='w3schools.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /python/demopage.htm (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
[29400] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

2. Bundling certifi's cacert in pyinstaller as data. Doing so yields the same results as 1
3. Using parameter verify=False. This one actually works, but is rather unsafe for the data I am actually pulling. I would like to avoid using this solution if possible
4. Compiling pyinstaller in none directory mode instead of one file mode by adding:

```
coll = COLLECT(exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='lib'
)
```

to the .spec file.
Results are the same as building in one file mode.

## Summary of results

Using a simple requests.get() process with:

- No additional modifications: No problems
- Pyinstaller ONLY: No problems
- python-daemon ONLY: No problems
- both Pyinstaller and python-daemon: looks for cacert.pem in non existent folder
- both Pyinstaller and python-daemon with local copy of cacert.pem: SSL error
- both Pyinstaller and python-daemon with bundled copy of cacert.pem: SSL error
- both PyInstaller and python-daemon with one-dir mode: looks for cacert.pem in non existent folder

## Conclusion

Either I am make a very simple oversight, or there is a deeper underlying problem with how pyinstaller interacts with python-daemon and requests. Any insights would be helpful, I've been chasing this problem for a few weeks now.

Answer (score 0):

Pyinstaller unpacks and runs from /tmp (though this can be configured to be a different directory).

I found the below code which I use to do something similar to source and load a config file.  You have to determine whether you are running as a packaged binary or a script and then make the file location relative to where it is running from.  Alternatively, you can use an absolute path.  You could also make a runtime argument (arg.parse) and specify the full path at runtime.

The below code sets the file path as being the same directory from where the program is being run:

```
CERTIFICATE = 'cacert.pem'

# determine if application is a script file or frozen exe (pyinstaller)
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    elif __file__:
        application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    
    cert_path = os.path.join(application_path, CERTIFICATE)
```